# Почему CMake не находит GTest (Google Test)?

Tags: c++, cmake, gtest, google-test

Существует готовый проект. В одном из cmake-файлов отрабатывает такая конструкция:

```
find_package(GTest REQUIRED)
if (NOT GTest_FOUND)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Cannot find Google Test Framework!")
endif()
```

Как победить ошибку?

Как я установил GTest:
Ищу в поиске install gtest, первая ссылка: https://www.eriksmistad.no/getting-started-with-google-test-on-ubuntu/

Делаю как там:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtest-dev
cd /usr/src/gtest
sudo cmake CMakeLists.txt
sudo make
sudo cp *.a /usr/lib
```

Теперь прописываю GTEST_ROOT: 
GTEST_ROOT=/usr/lib

Comment: установить gtest?

Comment: Установил... Но не ищет GTest

Comment: Gtest нужно не просто установить, а с уважением:) нормально он только под генту ставитсв

Comment: По ссылке странная инструкция. Если это linux, то GTEST_ROOT не надо прописывать, если библиотеки и заголовки установлены в системные пути. В этой инструкции я не вижу, чтобы заголовки устанавливались в систему.

Answer (score 0):

Выставьте `GTEST_ROOT` либо как переменную окружения, либо как переменную CMake в путь к GTest. Альтернативные пути интеграции прописаны в [официальной документации](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/README.md).

Comment: Выставил - не помогает. Как cmake заставить заново генерировать или это не нужно делать?

Comment: Добавьте в свой вопрос все шаги, которые попробовали сделать. С указанием путей и содержимого тех директорий, куда эти пути указывают.

Comment: Дополнил вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Приведу пример на мой взгляд элегантного подключения gtest к проекту с помощью cMake.

```
ExternalProject_Add(
gtest
URL https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/master.zip
PREFIX ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/gtest
# Disable install step
INSTALL_COMMAND ""
)

ExternalProject_Get_Property(gtest source_dir binary_dir)

add_library(libgtest IMPORTED STATIC GLOBAL)
add_dependencies(libgtest gtest)

set_target_properties(libgtest PROPERTIES
   "IMPORTED_LOCATION" "${binary_dir}/googlemock/gtest/libgtest.a"
   "IMPORTED_LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES" "${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT}"
)

add_library(libgmock IMPORTED STATIC GLOBAL)
add_dependencies(libgmock gtest)

set_target_properties(libgmock PROPERTIES
    "IMPORTED_LOCATION" "${binary_dir}/googlemock/libgmock.a"
    "IMPORTED_LINK_INTERFACE_LIBRARIES" "${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT}"
)

include_directories("${source_dir}/googletest/include"
                "${source_dir}/googlemock/include")
```

Так сборка будет дольше так как уйдет время на сборку самой либы но так можно смело отдавать свой код другому человеку и он сразу сможет скомпилировать проект без потери времени на разбор как устроена либа и как ее собрать.